# SQL Server Availability Group - For Server failover and Site failover

Tags: sql-server

I have two sites.  Site "A" is local site and site "B" is remote site.

Inside local site "A" I would like to have two servers.  One master and one slave.  The slave will be used for reads and also for HA.  This I think is simple.

In addition to local site "A" I have remote site "B" which I would like to have two additional slave servers that will by synchronized from the master in site "A".  Unlike the slave in site "A" those slaves will not be used for reads and I do not want to use them for failover.  The only time I use them is when I switch sites. In such as case, I will manually make one of them into master and start using site "B" as master slave site.

Is such a setup possible?

Thanks
Avi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing sounds exactly like a Distributed Availability Group.